# postgresql gives permission issues

Tags: database, apache, postgresql

Postgresql is not cooperating. I did a yum of postgresql and postgresql-server and that seemed to be fine. I then tried to `` and it gives and error message:

> createdb: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  Ident
>   authentication failed for user "postgres"

If I remove the user it gives the same error just with my username. I'm on a Centos OS. I want it to work with apache and php after I figure out to create a database.

When I run `/usr/bin/postgres` it gives an error:

> /usr/bin/postgres does not know where to find the server configuration
>   file. You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or
>   set the PGDATA environment variable.

Can't figure it out. Did I miss a configuration step? I thought doing yum would work out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it is configured for ident authentication which requires you to login as the linux user postgres ie:

```
su postgres
```

and then run the createdb command. Other method would be to locate your pg_hba.conf probably in something like /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data and switch to trust authentication. That way you can connect using -U postgres with any linux account and it will let you in without verifying the password. Then you can setup required usernames and passwords and then switch to something more secure like md5.

Comment: So I edited pg_hba.conf to include at the end of the file: `host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust`. I then tried to restart the server but it said `pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset`

Comment: You were right about becoming postgres and then creating a user. My problem was I didn't think I had a user named postres. I solved the problem by becoming root then becoming postgres and then createuser to create the user I want

Comment: Add the following to your .profile or .bash_profile to solve the data directory issue: `export PGDATA=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/data/`